# fresh installed pwa does not show content

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I used [A Simple Progressiv Web App Tutorial](https://medium.com/james-johnson/a-simple-progressive-web-app-tutorial-f9708e5f2605) to get in touch with PWA.

Now I face the problem, that I have changed the `h1` content from 
`Hello World!` to `Hello World, Minamo!`. Which is shown perfectly if I open up the page in the safari browser on the iPhone.

When I store the PWA on my iPhone, through `Share > Add To Homescreen` and open up the PWA on the home screen, it shows me the *old content*: `Hello World!`.

**How do I get the newest Version with the correct content - which is shown in the Safari Browser - as PWA stored on the iPhone?**

Note: Before I added the new PWA to the home screen, I deleted the old version of the PWA.

Here my files:

#### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/hello-icon-152.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="white"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Hello World">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/hello-icon-144.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
</head>
<body class="fullscreen">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Hello World, Minamo!</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### js/main.js

```js
window.onload = () => {
  'use strict';

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('./sw.js');
  }
}
```

### sw.js

```js
var cacheName = 'hello-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/css/style.css',
  '/js/main.js'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you did not totally clear out everything. Typically a PWA loads from the cache. If there are changes those are loaded in the background if the app is open for more than a few seconds. The NEXT time the app is opened, you see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the 'index.html' that is being rendered now on your app is that that was cached when you first started the app, hence you'll have the clear your cache memory for that app.

**on my iPhone6s I will go to**

1. Settings
2. Safari
3. Advanced
4. Website Data
5. Edit (top right)
6. Then clear the data for my app by clicking the red icon.

Launch your app and you should see your new data

Of course you don't expect your users to always do this when you make update to your web app's content, And to avoid that there's the [Update Service worker method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) that you can use to update your service workers.